# Highchart - spline chart - Single value or horizontal line series draws ON the x axis

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

while using the older version of highchart - 2.1.6, if a plot had only one value or a series of same values, it would plot at the middle of the screen as below.[image]

But, ever since i have upgraded the version of the highchart to 4.1.5, the line sticks to the bottom, on the xaxis. like this. 
[image]

I am looking for the option to set it back to normal but, didn't find it yet. Help me out with this please.

I have tried pointPadding on the series and even maxPadding on the yAxis, but no use.
Here is the fiddle where it is replicated -

http://jsfiddle.net/ka4p4sym/2/

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
```

Comment: Could you replicate it? Doesn't happen here: http://jsfiddle.net/ka4p4sym/

Comment: @Ondkloss I have update the fiddle with my change - it occurs here - http://jsfiddle.net/ka4p4sym/1/

Comment: @Ondkloss updated the fiddle to http://jsfiddle.net/ka4p4sym/2/